# Insertion at the end of doubly linked list

Tags: c, data-structures

I am only able to view the very first element of the input.The code is given as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct d_list{
    int data;
    struct d_list *next;
    struct d_list *prev;
}node;
```

// Without recursively calling the insert function.

```
typedef node *list;
main(){
    printf("Enter data(y/n)?");
    char ch;
    scanf("%s",&ch);
    int n;
    list head;
    list temp;
    list tail;
    head=tail=temp=NULL;
    if(ch=='y'||ch=='Y'){
        printf("Enter data");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        temp=(list)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->data=n;
        temp->next=temp->prev=NULL;
        head=temp;
        tail=temp;
    }
    printf("Enter more data..?(y/n)");
    scanf("%s",&ch);
    while(ch=='y'||ch=='Y'){
        printf("Enter data");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        temp=(list)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->data=n;
        temp->prev=tail;
        temp->next=NULL;
        tail->next=temp;
        tail=temp;
        printf("Enter more data..?(y/n)");
        scanf("%s",&ch);
    }

    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        printf("%d",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    getch();
}
```

I want to display all the inputs in the order they were input.What is the problem here?

Comment: The code is working fine.I ran it and i got the output in the same order of the input .
`:~$ cc dll.c
:~$ ./a.out
Enter data(y/n)?y
Enter data3
Enter more data..?(y/n)y
Enter data4
Enter more data..?(y/n)y
Enter data5
Enter more data..?(y/n)n
345`

Comment: Code is working fine for me...

Comment: Please fix this: `scanf("%s",&ch);` Your code already invokes undefined behavior for any non-empty input string.

Answer (score 3):

Your logic of the code is correct but here is the error: make `scanf("%s",&ch);` as `scanf(" %c",&ch);`

Comment: actually `scanf("%s",&ch);` is correct - second argument should be a pointer to char, and `&ch` is a pointer to char

Comment: @mangusta Even if you enter a single character, it will write the `'\0'` past `ch`. So it's only good as long as you don't use it, which doesn't make it very good indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, simplest code for your problem, the changes I have made are,

> changed scanf("%s",&ch); to scanf("%c",&ch);

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

using namespace std;
typedef struct d_list{
    int data;
    struct d_list *next;
    struct d_list *prev;
}node; 

typedef node *list;
int main()
{
    char ch;
    int n;
    list head = NULL,temp = NULL,tail = NULL;  
    do{
        printf("\nEnter data ?(y/n):\n");
        scanf("%c",&ch); 
        if(ch=='n'||ch=='N')
            break;
        printf("\nEnter data :\n");
        scanf_s("%d",&n);
        temp=(list)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->data=n;
        temp->next=NULL;
        if(head == NULL)
        {  
            temp->prev=NULL;
            head=temp; 
        }
        else
        {
            temp->prev=tail;
            tail->next=temp;
        }
        tail=temp;  
    }while(ch=='y'||ch == 'Y');

    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        printf("\n%d",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    } 
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why did you vote down ? Plz give me the reason, so that I can improve.